# How to reproject raster created from netCDF file?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, netcdf

I have a netCDF file that I turn into a RasterBrick and would like to reporject. However, this results in an error. How can I solve this?

```
> dat
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 1100, 1200, 1320000, 365  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent     : 3500000, 4700000, 2100000, 3200000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=lcc +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +lat_1=35 +lat_2=65 +x_0=4000000 +y_0=2800000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : pr_hyras_1_2006_v5-0_de.nc 
names      : X2006.01.01.18.00.00, X2006.01.02.18.00.00, X2006.01.03.18.00.00, X2006.01.04.18.00.00, X2006.01.05.18.00.00, X2006.01.06.18.00.00, X2006.01.07.18.00.00, X2006.01.08.18.00.00, X2006.01.09.18.00.00, X2006.01.10.18.00.00, X2006.01.11.18.00.00, X2006.01.12.18.00.00, X2006.01.13.18.00.00, X2006.01.14.18.00.00, X2006.01.15.18.00.00, ... 
Date/time  : 2006-01-01 18:00:00, 2006-12-31 18:00:00 (min, max)
varname    : pr 

> projectRaster(dat, "+init=epsg:31467")
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'extent': no slot of name "ptr" for this object of class "SpatVector"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you read the help for `projectRaster` you'll see the `Usage` section:

```
 projectRaster(from, to, res, crs, method="bilinear", 
              alignOnly=FALSE, over=FALSE, filename="", ...)
```

which means if you don't name the second argument, it thinks its "to", which is:

```
  to: Raster* object with the parameters to which 'from' should be
      projected
```

but you are giving the CRS as the second parameter so it fails.

Instead, name the parameter. Here's a test.

```
> r = raster(matrix(1:12, 3,4),crs="epsg:27700")
```

Unnamed argument:

```
> projectRaster(r, "+init=epsg:4326")
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘res’ for signature ‘"character"’
In addition: Warning message:
In min(dim(to)[1:2]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Named argument:

```
> projectRaster(r, crs="+init=epsg:4326")
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 3, 4, 12  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 3.46e-06, 2.98e-06  (x, y)
extent     : -7.55645, -7.556436, 49.76619, 49.7662  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0.7147044, 11.23941  (min, max)
```

The only thing confusing me is the reference to `SpatVector` in your error message which is a `terra` package thing and not a `raster` package thing. But if your object really is a RasterBrick then this will fix it.